# UDP test program (dropper/duplicator/reorderer)

Tags: udp

When using UDP datagrams can get reordered/dropped/duplicated. However this is unlikely to occur when you test with 127.0.0.1.

Is there already a program that forwards UDP packets, dropping/duplicating/reordering them?

Expected usage:

```
udpdegrade 0.0.0.0 1234   127.0.0.1 1235   0.02        0.02       30 0.05
           bind address   sendto address   drop prob.  dup prob.  reorder params
```

If no, what features should it have, how should it be configured, how should it be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are tools for this.  You're looking for a network simulator/emulator.

**WANem** is one option http://wanem.sourceforge.net/ another option is **netem** http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem.  I think you're asking whether or not there's value in developing another tool for this?  Not sure.  Both WANem and netem are imperfect; there are other commercial products such as [Shunra](http://www.shunra.com/) which try to more closely replicate real network behavior.

As a developer I've implemented re-ordering and loss directly in my application code to test its robustness to those events.  Perhaps code that does that generically would be useful (network emulation from inside your application)...

Comment: Ha, we both posted the same thing simultaneously